# npm config node-options not passing to node.js NODE_OPTIONS ENV

Tags: node.js, npm, openssl

I'm trying to set a global npm config `node-options` as below but it's not working.  According to [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#node-options), it should be a straight pass through like this right?

`npm config set -g node-options='--use-openssl-ca'`

Here's the `npm config list` output after above command:

```
:/# npm config list
; "global" config from /usr/local/etc/npmrc

node-options = "--use-openssl-ca"
```

I've tried user config also (so no `-g` option) but still doesn't work.  I also tried Node versions 12, 14 and 16 and still no luck.

Setting the ENV var NODE_OPTIONS directly (i.e. `export NODE_OPTIONS="--use-openssl-ca"`) works as expected.

Has anyone used the npm config `node-options` before successfully and have an example to show?